# Add action to UIBarButtonItem dynamically Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)))

@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Hello")
}
```

That's the code for my UIBarButton but when I click on it it doesn't print "Hello", what could be the problem?

EDIT: Here are my viewcontroller
It simply control a button that when it's clicked show the spinner with its control, but as I said before the button on toolbar doesn't work

```
class FilterViewController: UIViewController {

var search: Search?

let categoriesSpinnerDelegate = CategoriesPickerDelegate()

@IBOutlet weak var generalSpinner: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var categoriesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryRow: UIView!

var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.topViewController?.title = "Filtri"

    // Set border and click action
    self.categoryRow.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.categoryRow.layer.borderColor = Raccoltacase.lightGray.cgColor
    self.categoryRow.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(sender:))))

    // Create toolbar and attach it to pickerView
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    //toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    self.doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton!], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    generalSpinner.addSubview(toolBar)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func categoriesButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.generalSpinner.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    self.generalSpinner.dataSource = categoriesSpinnerDelegate
    self.generalSpinner.delegate = categoriesSpinnerDelegate
    self.generalSpinner.isHidden = false
}

@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("Hello")
}
}
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ico.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
When i use `pickerView.addSubView(toolbar)` the toolbar was placed behind the pickerview and so it was no clickable. I solved it adding the toolbar manually from storyboard with `General Spinner.top = Picker Toolbar.bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are showing the picker sometimes (and dismissing it when user presses the done button), here is my solution:

1. Add a **UITextField** to the view in storyboard (and make the tintColor transparent (clearColor))
2. Add the **UIToolbar** as **inputAccessoryView** to the **UITextField**
3. Add the **UIPickerView** as **inputView** to the toolbar (Also see the note below)

Below is a sample code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.inputView = generalSpinner
    textField.inputAccessoryView = getToolbar()
}

func getToolbar() -> UIToolbar {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame:         CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 40))
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton!], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolBar
}
```

**Note**: In case the UIPickerView is already in the storyboard (or a subview of another view), make sure to remove it in the first line of viewDidLoad (as shown below):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  generalSpinner.removeFromSuperview()
  textField.inputView = generalSpinner
  textField.inputAccessoryView = getToolbar()
}
```

Comment: My toolbar is attached to a PickerView, so I think I don't need to use it

Comment: Can you explain your situation a bit? Like is the picker always visible or is it shown on button click or something like that?

Comment: Check my edited question, I have a button when it's clicked shows the picker with the toolbar attached to it

Comment: The best and easiest way would be to change the button to textfield(giving it similar background as a button if needed) And use the above code.

Comment: I've added a screen about how my pickerview is, check it.